# Convincing a company to add new technologies and techniques to their body of standards?

Tags: architecture, standards

I  work in an organization that relies heavily on technology standards. For the most past this is great and helps provide direction to developers and helps them move across teams really easily.

However in the past year I have discovered more effective ways of doing things using new technologies and I am struggling to get these strategies added to the technology road map.

Has anyone had this experience and if so what have they done to bring about change in the organization?

Comment: Consider changing your question/title to more accurately reflect the question you're asking in the body text.  :)

Comment: @Pistos, I edited the title to reflect the question.  While that is a great Clint Eastwood movie.. for future people searching this site it won't be much benefit to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With permission, offer to do a small project using the new technologies. Demonstrate its value and that it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in what I think is quite a backward and archaic shop.  We're still using CVS (!), Perl was only upgraded from 5.6 to 5.8 this week, and we came on board PHP 5 from 4 only this year.  If you get any success, let me know :) but based on experience, I can tell you that sometimes a big factor that impedes adoption of new technologies is not so much that the benefits and superiority of the technology is not known or acknowledged, but rather that there are more pressing priorities that management wants to get to.

If the team, department or company is getting by with currently used technologies, or even doing relatively well with them, then changing to or even test driving new stuff may not have sufficient justification yet.

Something I'm doing which you might consider is keeping a log of actual, tangible problems encountered with the technologies you consider inferior.  For example, in my case, I am keeping a log of the times when CVS gives any member of the team problems or frustration, especially when my preferred solution (git) would have saved the team time, or made possible a quick solution that CVS doesn't allow.  At some point, the amassed evidence might weigh heavily enough to support a decision to change to the new technology.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a small agency and I'm lucky enough to have direct access to my boss. When I find better ways to do my job I just make sure to let him know that there are options early in the job cycle.  Over time we've built a level of trust and every time I suggest a new approach there is less and less resistance.

I also make sure to document exactly how much time/money was saved using the new technology. This is easily the most compelling way to evolve your company's process. Bean counters love metrics!

Answer (score 0):

If what you make ends up being supported by a group of people other than yourself you need to live with Standards.  Can you imagine open source being developed without standards?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your case clearly and rationally to the appropriate decision maker(s), you stand a good chance of your proposal being accepted.

Some tips:

- Articulate the *value* of the change in standards. Make sure you express this in terms of *business value*, not just your own personal preference or convenience.
- Make sure you can demonstrate that the *costs and risks* of the change are small in comparison to the benefits. It helps massively if you can quantify these.

Examples:

- Standardising on the latest version of Java will mean we do not have to continue to maintain XX old code branches at the cost of £YYm per year.
- Adopting cloud infrastructure technology YY will reduce the time to provision new servers from 7 days to 1 day, which will enable us to bill customers for six days extra revenue. The risk is low because we have already trialled this technology successfully in Team A.